# What are these Strange Pattern Yugioh Cards

Tags: yu-gi-oh, playing-cards

I came across these bizarre looking Yugioh cards in my collection. They look nothing like my other cards. They clearly say Yugioh cards...are they knockoffs? If so, why do they look so bad.

[image: cards]
[image: backs of cards]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They clearly say Yugioh cards...are they knockoffs?

**Those are fake cards**<sup>*</sup>, although from the image I see they use the actual names of existing, original cards, and even the correct effects (for example [Hiro's Shadow Scout](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Hiro%27s_Shadow_Scout)).

*Further reading on [counterfeit cards](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Counterfeit).*

<sup>*</sup>I know they are fake because... experience. But just to point out some of the details:

- The YuGiOh logo on the back of the card is clearly not the same as the original YuGiOh logo
- The colors are off. Those monsters look red (like trap cards) and trap cards look more like the monster color
- The displayed attack on the monster card mimics the one on OCG/Anime (displayed on the bottom right in its own box), whilst the text is English - a clear mix-up

Comment: Thanks for the quick and detailed answer. They just look so bad/different that I didn’t think they could ever pass for knock-offs. Glad to have it confirmed though.

Comment: @AlexK yeah, at most you could use them as proxies? lol